# Close html page after flash (swf) animation ends

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, flash

I have published my flash file to a html page. How would I automatically close this page once the flash animation ends. I can tell flash via actionscript to stop, but I need the whole page to automatically close.

Just tried to use javascript to tell website to close after 5 seconds (time of animation). Didn't want to work. Time of close does NOT matter just as long as it closes after animation. Here is code:

```
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Splashload</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <script>
function loaded()
{

    window.setTimeout(CloseMe, 500);
}

function CloseMe() 
{
    window.close();
}
</script>
    <body>
        <div align="center" id="flashContent">
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Splashload.swf" width="766" height="750" id="Splashload" style="float: none; vertical-align:middle">
                <param name="movie" value="Splashload.swf" onLoad="loaded()" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>

            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For testing purposes, here is the SWF fie

http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/512654/Splashload-swf.html

Comment: JavaScript uses milliseconds on it's timers, you need to do `setTimeout(CloseMe, 5000)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can call CloseMe function via [ExternalInterface.call(functionName, param);](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call%28%29) when animation is complete